# spark streaming and twitter custom receiver

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, twitter4j, spark-streaming

i create a thread in my custom twitter receiver to change follow users :

```
first = true ;
if (first) {
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (true)
                            try {
                                System.out.println("begin ---------------");
                                sleep(60 * 1000);
                                // get scores from mongodb
                                ArrayList<Long> r = getScores("Twitter", "polScore","CUCB");

                                if (r.size() != 0){

                                 FilterQuery query = new FilterQuery();
                                query.follow(arrayListToArray(r));

                                // follow new users
                                newTwitterStream.filter(query);

                                System.out.println("Changed !!!!!!!!");

                                }
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("Exception : "
                                        + e.getMessage());
                            }
                    }
                }.start();
                first = false;
            }
```

in my `TwitterStreamingFactory` i store `rdd` of score in `mongodb`  every 1 minute , the thread in receiver wait 60 seconds to get scores from `mongoDB` .
the problem is sometimes the thread get score before my spark streaming context store them in `mongodb` , is there any way to handle that like wait and notify ???

in the main i have this :

```
TwitterReceiver receiver = new TwitterReceiver(
                twitter.getAuthorization(), filteru,...);

JavaStreamingContextFactory contextFactory = new TwitterStreamingFactory(
                receiver,...);
```

i create an instance of twitter receiver with users to follow in the beginning and i use it in spark streaming , what i went to do is to change users to follow in spark streaming without stopping spark streaming .

thank you ,

Comment: Not sure what you are trying here. Wait 60 secs from which moment? The `newTwitterStream.filter(query);` is supposed to create a new stream in a existing streaming context? Could you post the code where you use this?

Comment: @maasg i changed my question , thank you for your help

Comment: Still not clear to me what you are asking. "is there any way to handle that like wait and notify" -- you would like to synchronize some actions, but what actions?